# How do you customise the Group subscription format

Tags: organic-groups

I have assigned user profiles the field Group Type and set it to default as "is group type" so that users can subscribe to each others profiles. This is all fine but i would like to customise the link that allows the users to subscribe, i.e. the display format 'Group subscription'. It currently says: "Subscribe to group", "Unsubscribe from group" or "You are the group manager". Is it possible to customise this text?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [string override module](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides)

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.